# Question about the property of almost surely.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

1. If $f= \bar{f}$, a.e., $g=\bar{g}$ a.e. then $f+g= \bar{f}+\bar{g}$ a.e.
   The statement seems true to me, but I am not sure.

Is it correct that $\{(f+g \neq \bar{f}+\bar{g})\} \subset \{(f \neq \bar{f})\} \cup \{(g \neq \bar{g})\}$ ?

Where $\{(f \neq \bar{f})\}$ is the set of measure zero, so by the finite sub-additivity of measure, my statement is true.

The comments by Sassatelli Giulio successfully answered my first question.

Now I am curious about the inverse part, or more specifically,

2. If $m=n$ a.e., can I say the positive parts (defined as $max(m,0)$ for $m$)are also equivalent a.e.? I think it is a natural corollary of 1., but can not prove it.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: The last paragraph makes no sense. Unfortunately, we are not mind readers.

Comment: I think the measurability issue needs care. You did not assume $f,g$ are measurable, while answers and comments seems to take it for granted. Two non-measurable functions can be equal a.e. (For instance if they are equal everywhere), but your statement may be false if $f,g$ are not assumed measurable and the measure space is weired. (Neglect this comment if you have not learned abstract measure space, only the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$)

Comment: If I assume $f,g$ are measurable, then a more direct proof for 2 is:

For a fixed $x_0$, 
\begin{equation}
f(x_0)=g(x_0)\implies \max\{f(x_0),0\}=\max\{g(x_0),0\}.
\end{equation}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
\max\{f(x_0),0\}\ne\max\{g(x_0),0\}\implies f(x_0)\ne g(x_0),
\end{equation}
i.e.
\begin{equation}
\left\{x: \max\{f(x),0\}\ne\max\{g(x),0\}\right\}\subseteq\{x:\ f(x)\ne g(x)\}.
\end{equation}
Which gives the conclusion .

Comment: Thank you! Good answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, yes. Your reasoning is correct.

For your second question, if $f = g$ almost everywhere, then it is also true that $\max(f, 0) = \max(g,0)$ almost everywhere. To see this, observe that if $f = g$ almost everywhere, then $|f| = |g|$ almost everywhere as well. Then use the fact that $\max(f, 0) = \frac{1}{2} (f+|f|)$ together with your first question.